# Let $\omega_t$ be a differential form. Prove that $\varphi(t)=\int_\lambda\omega_t$ is continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

For each $t\in T\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, let $w=\sum_{i=1}^na_i(t,x)dx_i$ a differential form in a open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $a_i:T\times U\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions. For each
rectifiable path $\lambda:[a,b]\to U$, prove that $\varphi:T\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi(t)=\int_\lambda\omega_t$ is continuous.

I was writing the definition of continuous functions to get some idea but i get nothing less this $$|\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)|=|\int_\lambda\omega_t-\int_\lambda\omega_{t_0}|=|\int_\lambda\sum_{i=1}^na_i(t,x)dx_i-\int_\lambda\sum_{i=1}^na_i(t_0,x)dx_i|$$
And after that tried to think in how could this gonna be $<\epsilon$. Anyway, i'm stuck on that question and need a help.

Comment: HINT: Use the fact that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Another hint: start by showing that $\int_\lambda \omega_t$ is continuous in $t$ for the case $\omega = a(t, x) dx_i$. Then, use the fact that the (finite) sum of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Ok, i'll follow those hints and see what's gonna happen. Thanks guys.

Comment: Oh, and sorry for my bad english, i'm learning yet.